# Filter not working using rich:extendedDataTable + modalpanel

Tags: datatable, richfaces, modal-dialog

I have a rich:extendedDataTable inside a rich:modalPanel and the default filter does not work.
I have already tested the same code outside the rich:modalPanel and it worked.
Is there something that I must do different to make it works inside the modalPanel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. I had a form around the modalpanel. Then I put it around the datatable and now it works.